# Cheap Windows hosting with configurable MAC address, shelvable for months when not in use

Tags: cloud-computing

Is there a cloud service (Google, Amazon, Oracle etc) that will allow me to create a virtual Windows development server and do the following:

- Allow me to log in to the server instance via RDP or remote console.
- Provide Windows Enterprise Server 2019 or let me install it.
- Provide MS SQL Server or let me install it.
- I have valid MS license keys & ISOs for both Windows & SQL server.
- Give me Windows command line plus GUI access.
- Allow me to install and run browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).
- Allow me to configure the server's MAC address (very important)
- Allow me to install COTS software (license manager tied to MAC address).
- Archive and save everything if I don't access it for several months or allow me to do this manually if I need to shelve it for a while.

Free would be nice but I can handle a couple bucks a month. I can't find an AWS option that explicitly lists these features. Apps plus data would be less than 100 GB. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: originally asked in SuperUser.

Comment: Several cloud providers will do most of your list. But "cheap" or "a couple bucks a month" is not really a usefull information... Also, backups can be automated but storage will be billed every month even if you delete and recreate the VM at every use... off course, you can download the backup, but in this case, why not just put all this locally as vms?

Comment: The mac adress part can be achieved on aws with elastic network interface, but will likelly add cost to your setup.